# SQL not group by expression, Find student who has taken at least 5 courses

Tags: sql, database, oracle

```
select s.name, s.id
from student s join takes t on t.id = s.id
where s.name like 'D%' 
group by s.name, s.id
having (
    select count(distinct c.course_id)
    from course c
    where c.dept_name = 'History' and c.course_id = t.course_id)>4
order by s.name
```

I am confused about how GROUP BY works. I am trying to find the students who has taken at least 5 courses from history department and name start with D.

Not sure with the nested subqueries...

```
course(course id, title, dept name, credits)
student(ID, name, dept name, tot_cred)
takes(ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to additionally `JOIN` with `course` table:

```
select s.name, s.id
from student s 
inner join takes t on t.id = s.id
inner join course c on c.course_id = t.course_id
where s.name like 'D%' and c.dept_name = 'History'
group by s.name, s.id
having count(distinct c.course_id) >= 5
```

The `WHERE` clause returns all students whose names start with a `'D'` **and** have taken *at least one* course in history department. The `HAVING` clause filters out any students with 4 or less *distinct* courses in history department.

Comment: Thanks! I thinking I need to learn more about inner join. but for student who has not taken at least 5 course, I thought I can find out by doing ...<5, but the result is confusing. as the number of student who has taken at least 5 course is 0, so who has not taken at least 5 course should be all the student whose name starts with D, based on the result should be 6 people. but if i do <5, then there is only three people... May I ask why?

Comment: @RhumB How many `s.id`s do you get as result if you remove completely the `HAVING` clause?

Comment: @RhumB Also note that there is an additional predicate in `WHERE` clause, namely `c.dept_name = 'History'`. This restricts results to students having taken *at least one* course in history department.

Comment: I get 3 after removing.

Comment: Oh! my bad, it should be taking at least 5 courses from history department.. and I thought c.dept_name = 'History' takes care of that ...@GiorgosBetsos

Comment: How can I make sure it counts only the courses from history department?